# ACF Unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING

Tags: php, advanced-custom-fields, escaping

I'm running the Advanced Custom Fields Pro plugin. When I implement the following code for the repeater field, I get this PHP error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING,
>   expecting ',' or ';'

```
            <?php
            while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
                if( have_rows('logos') ):
                    while ( have_rows('logos') ) : the_row();
                        $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_sub_field('brands'), 'logo' );
                        echo "<div class=\"quarter\">" "<img src=\"" .$image[0]. "\" alt=\"Logo\"></div>";
                    endwhile;
                endif;
            ?>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Have I escaped the quotes correctly here? I can't see the error.

I've also tried using strings instead of escaping the quotes:

```
echo '<div class="quarter">' '<img src="' .$image[0]. '" alt="Logo"></div>';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your string example is wrong. You´re ending the echo statement right after opening the `<div>`. It should look like this:

`echo '<div class="quarter"><img src="' .$image[0]. '" alt="Logo"></div>';`